# Unable to change PM2 logs path

Tags: pm2

I am using pm2 4.5.4
As of now, I am using the default logs path which is under $HOME/.pm2/logs. I want move the logs under /apps so that I stopped  the service and start with --log

```
pm2 start appA --log /apps/logs
```

But still logs are generated in the default path.

Anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for pulling the trigger so late. I found the problem. I had to delete the pm2 instance and then run as follows

pm2 start app.js --name appA -o /apps/logs/out.log -e /apps/logs/error.log